# How to add a condition in commandButton ( Primefaces)?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

I'm a beginner in primefaces framework, I want that my commandButton verify if the selected item is "All" to call a specific method allBooks() , and if another item is choosen: to call another method : loadBook()

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bookBean.selectedBook.id}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select a book :" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bookBean.selectedBooksItems}" />
    <p:ajax execute="bookSelect" event="change" listener="#{bookBean.loadBook}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:commandButton id="validate" action="#{bookBean.requestBook}" value="Validate"/>
```

Comment: That's business logic; Doing it in your view is a code smell. It should happen in your backing bean

Answer (score 1):

Do it in your actionListener method

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bookBean.selection}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select a book :" itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="#{'ALL'}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bookBean.options}" />
    <p:ajax/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:commandButton actionListener="#{bookBean.loadButtonActionListener}" value="Load"/>
```

---

```
public void loadButtonActionListener(ActionEvent event){

    if(this.selection.equals("ALL")) {
        this.allBooks();
    } else {
        this.loadBook(this.selection);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Angelika use my commandbutton and try again. also please update your question with your bean code

Answer (score 0):

commandButton ajaxified by default so this snippet work as you expect:

```
    <h:form>
        <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{myBean.selected}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="ALL" itemValue="ALL" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="NONE" itemValue="NONE" />

        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:commandButton value="Validate" actionListener="#{myBean.doAction}" />
    </h:form>
```

here is declared bean:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean {

private String selected;

public MyBean() {
}

public String getSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(String selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

public void doAction() {
    if (selected.equals("ALL")) {
        System.out.println("ALL Called!");
    } else if (selected.equals("NONE")) {
        System.out.println("NONE Called");
    }
}
}
```

UPDATE:

if you want to add ajax change event to `selectOneMenu` just nest this line in `selectOneMenu` element 
`<p:ajax listener="#{myBean.doAction}" />`